# Getting Bonjour Address with IP Address and/or Host Name

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ip-address, bonjour

I'm working on an iPhone-iPad app with Objective-C. I need to get the Bonjour Address of the device. I understand this address is generated with the hostname of the device, which I've already got.

Could anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Mikywan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see following

```
service = [[NSNetService alloc] initWithDomain:@"local." type:@"_music._tcp" name:serviceName];

[service setDelegate:delegateObject];

[service resolveWithTimeout:5.0]; // This code will return an address on delegate method`
```

following delegate methods will get fired depending on the result

```
 netServiceDidResolveAddress

   netService:didNotResolve:
```

[See Docs for more detailed description](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/NSNetServiceProgGuide/Articles/ResolvingServices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001078-97962)